# MySQL and ADO - hopeless?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, ado

Tearing hair out and googling all weekend. I am frantically converting an ASP site to use MySQL.  Am I correct in thinking that I would be barking up the wrong tree to try to use recordset commands to get data in and out of MySQL via ODBC and should only use MySQL procedures?  If so I face a nightmare, I think as have then to work out how to capture the returned values.

Sorry if this sounds hideously ignorant, but no idea where to turn.

DETAILS:

```
Set SConn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};"_
& "SERVER=" & SQLServer & ";"_ 
& "DATABASE=" & SQLDbase & ";"_
& "UID=" & SQLUser & ";PWD=" & SQLPW  & "; OPTION=35;"

SQL = "SELECT tblNodes.SingleSiteChildID "
SQL = SQL & "FROM tblNodes "
SQL = SQL & "WHERE (((tblNodes.NodeID)=" & m_lngNodeID & "));"


set RS=server.CreateObject("adodb.Recordset")
RS.CursorType = 1
RS.LockType = 2
RS.Open SQL, conn


 With RS
If not .Fields("SingleSiteChildID")  >0 or isnull(.Fields("SingleSiteChildID")) then
    If m_lngChildCount>0 then
        .Fields("SingleSiteChildID")=0
            m_lngSingleSiteChildID=0
     Else
            .Fields("SingleSiteChildID")=null
            m_lngSingleSiteChildID=null
     End if
     .UPDATE
End if
END WITH
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to give more details if you want your question answered. Some (short) sample code that demonstrates your issue would help a lot.

Comment: You can run direct SQL queries against MySQL ODBC if you want to. Could you elaborate on the problems you are having and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have added a bit of code to my post.  Falls over whatever I seem to do with the locktypes or cursor types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Recordset and Command objects in exactly the same way you are use other databases at the moment.

If you use DSNs, all you need to do is create a system DSN to the MySQL DB, although a DSN-less connection is a better way of doing it.

Head to the MySQL site to install the [ODBC drivers](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) then your connection string will look something like this:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; Server=localhost; uid=user_name; pwd=password; database=db_name; option=67108899; port=3306;
```

Do a quick Google to check that the options specified there are correct for you, I have ripped this from a working Classic ASP site that uses MySQL.

Simply switching the connection string should allow you to migrate very simply to a new DB type.  Do check that all your SQL commands conform to MySQL standards, and do not use words specific to MSSQL or Access, e.g. `TOP` is MS only, use `LIMIT` for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Have added the sort of think I am trying to do and that worked cheerfully with Access as a backend.  Here, I either get odd errors or nothing much happens.

Comment: The error message I am constantly getting is: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Comment: I tend to use `rs.CursorType = 2` and `rs.CursorLocation = 3` for MySQL, that doesn't sound like your problem.  Presumably the error is on the line with `rs.open`? Is the only thing you've changed the connection string?

Comment: Yes. Have narrowed the thing down to recordset UPDATES. I *think* this may be a long standing issue judging from my somewhat soul-destroying adventures in Google-land. Thank you for your help though. I shall try your cursortype & cursorlocation though pretty sure I have tried every combination :(